# How to fix discord.js-commando bot responding to unknown commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js, commando

I'm creating the client with the `unknownCommandResponse` property set to `false`:

```
const client = new CommandoClient({
  commandPrefix: '$',
  unknownCommandResponse: false,
  owner: '291048060845424640',
  disableEveryone: true
});
```

Yet when I try `$kasopdkoakwdokapowkdo`, it responds with:

```
Unknown command. Use $help or @Mysticonomy#2670 help to view the command list.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was the right way to do it until the 18th of January: they decided to make the bot "unknown command" and "error" replies overridable, by allowing custom commands that will run instead.
This change may not be well-documented yet, but has been pushed to the [`master`](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/tree/master) branch with [this commit](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/commit/09f883317da6d7d8431367ffff827939dfbb2d74#diff-cf27c1d543e886c89cd9ac8b8aeaf05b) by [Gawdl3y](https://github.com/Gawdl3y). This topic comes from [this issue](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/issues/193), and is also listed in the "Done" column of the "Important stuff" project [[link](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/projects/1#column-3472961)].

If you want to make it work like in the past, you'll need to use a previous version; you won't be able to update the library to add new functionalities without updating this part of the code too.

With this update, you can create a new command by extending the `Command` class (as usually) and then adding two properties set to `true`: `unknown` and `hidden`.
If you want an example, you can look directly at the default [`unknown-command`](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/blob/master/src/commands/util/unknown-command.js) by the author of the change:

```
module.exports = class UnknownCommandCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'unknown-command',
      group: 'util',
      memberName: 'unknown-command',
      description: 'Displays help information for when an unknown command is used.',
      examples: ['unknown-command kickeverybodyever'],
      unknown: true,
      hidden: true
    });
  }

  run(msg) {
    return msg.reply(
      `Unknown command. Use ${msg.anyUsage(
                'help',
                msg.guild ? undefined : null,
                msg.guild ? undefined : null
            )} to view the command list.`
    );
  }
};
```

Remember to avoid loading the default `unknown-command`: it'll be loaded by default by [`CommandoRegistry.registerDefaultCommands()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/class/CommandoRegistry?scrollTo=registerDefaultCommands) unless you explicitly tell it not to do it.
To avoid that, add `unknownCommand: false` to the options when you load those commands.

```
client.registry.registerDefaultCommands({
  unknownCommand: false
});
```

Comment: It is telling me an unknown command is already registered, but I am pretty sure I haven't registered one.

Comment: Ok. I looked at the one on the docs. How would I create my own unknown-command?

Comment: You should create a new command like if it was a normal one, just add `unknown: true` and `hidden: true` to its options

Comment: But then it tells me an unknown command is already registered.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. I've edited my answer to explain it.